# Can't reference inner class from a static context, but only if outer class is generic

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

The following won't compile:

```
class Outer<T> {
    class Inner {

    }

    static class Nested {
        Inner inner; // Error: Outer.this cannot be referenced from a static context
    }
}
```

However, if I remove `<T>`, it compiles.  Why the inconsistency?

Also, if I say `Outer.Inner inner;`, instead of `Inner inner;`, it compiles.  Again, why the inconsistency?

I'd expect an error in either all cases or none.  Could anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Well, you could reference `T` in `Inner`, e.g. a member variable. How would `Nested` know anything about the type of that if `Outer` is generic?

Comment: Change that line to `Outer<String>.Inner inner;` or some other specialisation of `T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why the inconsistency?**

I would say this is not inconsistency at all. This is basically a problem of understanding of generics. Consider the following code (Your modified code):

```
class Outer<T> {
    class Inner{
        T t;//Added this extra line
    }

    static class Nested {
        Inner inner; 
    }
}
```

In this above example is somewhat similar to what you have written only I have added a new variable `t` of type `T` which is the generics of `Outer` class in the class `Inner`. Now in this above example would not compile because there is a non-static or runtime reference present in the `Inner` class, so, when you declare `Inner` in a static class `Nested` the JAVA complier does not know the type of `T`, which is only declared in the runtime, so you get an error. But in your case you have done nothing like that but still the compiler does not know whether something like that is present or not. So it gives the error.

Now in the second case you have removed the generic `T` from the class declaration of the `Outer`. So there is no possibility of declaring variable `t` in the `Inner` class so there is no error.

In the third case you declared `Outer.Inner` for the type of variable `inner` and it compiled successfully. Here the compiler considered `Outer` as  **RAW TYPE**. But this type of raw type declarations should be avoided. So it would be better to write:

```
 Outer<?>.Inner inner;
```

Here Java compiler considers `Outer` to take any object as parameters which would inherit `Object`.

Comment: You think that you've learned all about inner classes and generics but then you come across something like this... I wonder what other weird interaction I have missed. Nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
class OuterClass {

    ...
    static class StaticNestedClass {
        ...
    }
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing class.

```
Static Nested Classes
```

As with class methods and variables, a static nested class is associated with its outer class. And like static class methods, a static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or methods defined in its enclosing class: it can use them only through an object reference.

Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass
```

For example, to create an object for the static nested class, use this syntax:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
 new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

For more information see the below click:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Nice explanation of inner and static classes, but it doesn't explain the problem in the question.